# Scraping OpenTable website using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, na

I'm trying to scrape the Open Table site with the use of Beautiful Soup.The code runs successfully, but the result I am getting has a lot of NA columns. Here is the code.

```
def parse_html(html):
    data, item = pd.DataFrame(), {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for i, resto in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_='rest-row-info')):
        item['name'] = resto.find('span', class_='rest-row-name-text').text

        booking = resto.find('div', class_='booking')
        item['bookings'] = re.search('\d+', booking.text).group() if booking else 'NA'

        rating = resto.select('div.all-stars.filled')
        item['rating'] = int(re.search('\d+', rating[0].get('style')).group()) if rating else 'NA'

        reviews = resto.find('span', class_='star-rating-text--review-text')
        item['reviews'] = int(re.search('\d+', reviews.text).group()) if reviews else 'NA'

        item['price'] = int(resto.find('div', class_='rest-row-pricing').find('i').text.count('$'))
        item['cuisine'] = resto.find('span', class_='rest-row-meta--cuisine').text
        item['location'] = resto.find('span', class_='rest-row-meta--location').text
        data[i] = pd.Series(item)
    return data.T


restaurants = pd.DataFrame()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = "https://www.opentable.com/new-york-restaurant-listings"
driver.get(url)
while True:
    sleep(1)
    new_data = parse_html(driver.page_source)
    if new_data.empty:
        break
    restaurants = pd.concat([restaurants, new_data], ignore_index=True)
    print(len(restaurants))
   # driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()

driver.close()
restaurants.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
print(restaurants)
```

and the results:

```
name    bookings    rating  reviews price   cuisine location
0   IL Carino Restaurant        1   NA  NA  3           Upper East Side
1   French Roast Uptown         10  NA  NA  3           Upper West Side
2   The Mermaid Inn Uptown      72  NA  NA  3           Upper West Side
3   Cafe Du Soleil              101 NA  NA  2           Upper West Side
4   The Leopard at des Artistes 24  NA  NA  4           Upper West Side
```

Any recommendation or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Rating, reviews and, cuisine columns are NA.

Comment: Did you already take a look into the html-file?  Furthermore, you could try to run your code without the type conversions (to int), in general it seems that you do several steps in one line of code which will make it hard for you to debug.

Comment: One way can be to simply use `pandas.read_html`. get the table and drop N/a values from the dataframe.

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you get in variable. Maybe you get empty values so later you get `NA`.  Maybe need some time to load all data or it send you different HTML then you see in web browser.

Comment: you are missingl all values in column so maybe you use wrong values in `find()`, `select()` and you should check what you get in HTML - maybe server send different HTML then you can see in browser or it uses javaScript to add elements but it needs more time for this.

Comment: I can't find `'div.all-stars.filled'` on this page - and code also can't find it - so you get `NA` for `rating`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see on this page

```
rating = resto.select('div.all-stars.filled')
```

and code also can't find it - so you get `NA` for `rating`

But this gives me strings like `4.5 stars out of 5`

```
rating = resto.select('.star-rating .star-rating-score')
#print(rating)
item['rating'] = rating[0]['aria-label'] if rating else 'NA'
```

---

I don't see on this page

```
resto.find('span', class_='star-rating-text--review-text')
```

and code also can't find it - so you get `NA` for `reviews`

But this gives me strings like `Awesome`, `Exceptional`

```
reviews = resto.select('div.review-rating-text span')
#print(reviews)
item['reviews'] = reviews[0].text if reviews else 'NA'
```

---

There are two elements with class `'rest-row-meta--cuisine'` and you get first so you get `$$$$`

```
item['cuisine'] = resto.find('span', class_='rest-row-meta--cuisine').text
```

but you should use `find_all` to get both and later use `[-1]` to get last one

```
item['cuisine'] = resto.find_all('span', class_='rest-row-meta--cuisine')[-1].text
```

and this gives me

```
Pizzeria
Italian
Sushi
Steak
Contemporary Italian
Pizzeria
American
Italian
American
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import re

def parse_html(html):
    data, item = pd.DataFrame(), {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for i, resto in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_='rest-row-info')):
        item['name'] = resto.find('span', class_='rest-row-name-text').text

        booking = resto.find('div', class_='booking')
        item['bookings'] = re.search('\d+', booking.text).group() if booking else 'NA'

        rating = resto.select('.star-rating .star-rating-score')
        #print(rating)
        item['rating'] = rating[0]['aria-label'] if rating else 'NA'

        reviews = resto.find('span', class_='star-rating-text--review-text')
        
        reviews = resto.select('div.review-rating-text span')
        #print(reviews)
        item['reviews'] = reviews[0].text if reviews else 'NA'

        item['price'] = int(resto.find('div', class_='rest-row-pricing').find('i').text.count('$'))
        
        item['cuisine'] = resto.find_all('span', class_='rest-row-meta--cuisine')[-1].text
        #print(item['cuisine'])
        
        item['location'] = resto.find('span', class_='rest-row-meta--location').text
        data[i] = pd.Series(item)
    return data.T


restaurants = pd.DataFrame()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.opentable.com/new-york-restaurant-listings"
driver.get(url)

while True:
    sleep(1)
    new_data = parse_html(driver.page_source)
    if new_data.empty:
        break
    restaurants = pd.concat([restaurants, new_data], ignore_index=True)
    print(len(restaurants))
   # driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
    
#driver.close()
restaurants.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
print(restaurants[['rating', 'reviews', 'cuisine']])
```

---

```
                rating      reviews               cuisine
0   4.5 stars out of 5      Awesome               Italian
1   4.5 stars out of 5      Awesome       French American
2   4.7 stars out of 5  Exceptional               Italian
3   4.8 stars out of 5  Exceptional               Seafood
4   4.4 stars out of 5      Awesome                French
..                 ...          ...                   ...
95  4.7 stars out of 5  Exceptional  Contemporary Italian
96    4 stars out of 5    Excellent              Pizzeria
97                  NA           NA              American
98  4.7 stars out of 5  Exceptional               Italian
99  4.4 stars out of 5      Awesome              American
```